# Civicrm fails to launch - Wordpress gives "The plugin does not have a valid header."

Tags: wordpress

We have been running CiviCRM 4.6.8 for a while now on our site. Last evening, while trying to access our site, Wordpress gives us this error: The plugin civicrm/civicrm.php has been deactivated due to an error: The plugin does not have a valid header.

we had plans to update to 4.7.9, so we backed up our SQL database and entire CiviCRM installation and proceeded with updating to 4.7.9 as per https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+WordPress. However, when point our browser to the upgrade url: http:///wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1, we get this error: You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

I would have thought that upgrading would have resolved any issues with invalid headers, but now it seems we have even further issues. Any ideas on how to go about resolving these problems?

Comment: please refer to : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-admin-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As regarrds the error message "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page", please have a look at the Civicrm wiki page at the following link.  https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Wordpress

If you get this error when trying to run the upgrade script, you most likely deactivated CiviCRM plugin during the upgrade process. You just have to visit /wp-admin/plugins.php and activate the plugin.

I  regret I can't help with the "valid header" problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. The invalid header problem seemed to have went away on its own - maybe a problem on hosting side. I have subsequently proceeded with the upgrade successfully. However, my Wordpress site and CiviCRM does not load anymore. If I deactivate the CiviCRM plugin from the Wordpress admin, my site loads fine. This is the error I get with CiviCRM plugin activated: This site can’t be reached

crm.iskcondurban.net’s server DNS address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: I am using Wordpress 4.3.5. Any idea why CiviCRM upgrade to 4.7.9, causes my site to fail to load?